# How to use multirow in the xltabular

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, xltabular

My table looks something like this

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm, bottom=2.5cm, a4paper, twoside, showframe=false]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, xltabular}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\usepackage{boldline} 

\lofoot{\upshape Stand: \today}
\title{Erklärung zur Anwendbarkeit der ISO 27001}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
 {
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{V{3} l | L{1.1} | c | L{0.9} | L{1.0} V{3}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
ID  &   \thead[l]{1} 
        &   \thead[l]{2} 
            &   \thead{3} 
                &   \thead{4}       \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\endfirsthead
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
ID  &   \thead[l]{1}
        &   \thead[l]{2}
            &   \thead{3}
                &   \thead{4}       \\

    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\endhead
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{}}
\endfoot
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\endlastfoot

    A.8.2   & \multicolumn{4}{cV{3}}{\LaTeX}             \\
    \hline
A.8.2.1 & 234 &   & CCC   &  \\ 
    \hline
A.8.2.2 & 234 &   & TTTT  &  \\ 
    \hline
A.8.2.3 & 234 &   & FFFF  &  \\ 
    \hline

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

How can I 'remove' the lines in column 2 and column 4. I marked the lines that I want to be removed.
[image]

Comment: REplace `\hline` with `\cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\cline{1-2}\cline{4-4}` instead of `\hline` on rows you want lines away.